# Instagram-like photo browser and a camera feature in android

Tags: android, camera, instagram, surfaceview, video-capture

I am developing one application, I am trying to develop same like instagram photo / video capture tool. I found very nice tutorial sample in iOS :

https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma

Does anybody know something similar library for android as well?

Please help. I have done with camera surfaceview. but its not stable, various devices have crashes.

Comment: Hi..Did you get any option to implement this feature? I am looking for the same.Please let me know if you have any option. Thanks